# Reading a text file and code jumps when using await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, windows-8.1

I am writing an app for windows 8.1 tablet and I am trying to read data from a text file I have saved (this text file is just over 1kb). The below code I have works on some occasions but mainly fails(debugging/stepping over the code will often see it succeed).

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
string fileName = "collections.json";
public Dictionary<string, string> masterDataObject;

private async void CallLoad()
{
   await this.Load();
}

public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> Load()
{
    //create a file
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    string fileContents = string.Empty;
    if (file != null)
    {
        //returns a JSON string
        fileContents = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);//WHY DOES IT JUMP AT THIS LINE?????
    }
    Dictionary<string, string> customerFromJSON = JsonCrt.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fileContents) ?? new Dictiy<string, string>();
    masterDataObject = customerFromJSON;
    return masterDataObject;
}
```

After stepping through the code several times I can see at the line
    fileContents = await.....
it drops out of the method and continues with the rest of the code that is not in my Load() method.

I have reviewed async and await and have really tried to understand it, but my understanding leaves me confused as to why this is happening.

I was under the belief that await meant that execution would stop until you get a response from the code you are calling (obviously not).

So how should I be using async to make it work properly, or is there a better alternative than this code?

I have looked and tried many options but so had no success, any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it drops out of the method and continues with the rest of the code that is not in my Load() method

That's exactly what it's ment to do, yield control to the calling site until the asynchronous operation completes.

I'm assuming your problem lays with the fact your `CallLoad` method is `async void` instead of `async Task`, thus cannot be awaited, and that's why you're seeing it continue without waiting for the internal async IO to complete.

> I was under the belief that await meant that execution would stop until you get a response from the code you are calling

That is still entirely true, *if* you **await** the async operation *all the way*

> So how should I be using async to make it work properly?

`async void` is ment only for top level event handlers. If `CallLoad` isn't used as one, it should be `async Task` and awaited: `await CallLoad();`

Comment: Thankyou, a small misunderstanding caused me three days of pain. changing void to Task<Dictionary<string, string>> resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

What await does behind the scenes:

- it creates a callback which contains the code **after** await
- it calls into the `xyzAsync()` function, registering the callback.
- if the asynchronous operation finishes, the callback is called.

So if you step through the code with a debugger, it will execute some other code if it hits **await** returning to the code after the **await** as soon as the asynchronous operation has finished.